# How to apply ajax or javascript in opensource php mini cart?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got this opensource php mini cart from youtube. Now the problem is how to apply it with ajax or javascript? So that everytime I add, remove and delete the items it wont refresh the whole page and will still work whether the javascript is on or off. If javascript is on the cart.php will use javascript and if it is off the cart.php will use php.

here's the code for add, remove and delete items in the cart. To look or download the full source code just click this link: [cart php source code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qlz9m3f3yzb56x0/AAAs3i6ajQfAuiGV9g4K8Ue2a?dl=0)

```
 if(isset($_GET['add'])){
        // use session to add the product
        $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['add']));

        while($quantity_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)){
            //if quantity is not equal in the database quantity
            if ($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]){
                $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+='1';      
            }
        }
        header('Location: '.$page);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
        $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['remove']]--;
        header('Location: '.$page);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
        $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['delete']]='0';
        header('Location: '.$page);
    }
```

Comment: The mysql PHP extension is deprecated since 2013 and removed in PHP 7.  Your code will not work in up-to-date and future servers.  There is a  newer, more powerful, and more flexible extension.

Comment: yeah I understand I just need the ajax or javascript implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to implement ajax in opencart. you just need to use it's own prebuilt Cart API and use it in your project.

First need to learn URL for Cart Functionalities

```
1. http:/ /< project location >/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add (with product_id and quantity as parameters)

2. http:/ /< project location >/index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove (with key as parameter which is cart id)

3. http:/ /< project location >/index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit (quantity[key] and value = 'quantity' as parameters
```

now you can use these code in Ajax requrest, assuming that your using jquery

```
var cart = {
    'add':function(product_id){
         $.get('http:/ /< project location >/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
         {product_id: product_id},
         function(data){}
     },
};
```

Like this you can make add, remove, edit and getcart function and you can add these functions to buttons or page load etc.

for example

```
<button onclick="cart.add('prod_01');> Add to Cart </button>
```

***Please Note***

these routes are basic opencart structure so no need to change it, you just have to use these routes in your javascript code to make ajax call and display the result, it's output is in JSON format, so it is very simple and easy to display a cart.

Good Luck